# What is the most efficient way to read tile data (MBTiles) from SQLite table by using AnyDAC (FireDAC)?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, anydac, firedac

### Background:

I'm working on a SQLite tile cache database (similar to [`MBTiles`](http://mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/) specification), consisting for now just from a single table `Tiles` with the following columns:

`X [INTEGER]` - horizontal tile index (not map coordinate)
`Y [INTEGER]` - vertical tile index (not map coordinate)
`Z [INTEGER]` - zoom level of a tile
`Data [BLOB]` - stream with a tile image data (currently PNG images)

All the coords to tile calculations are done in the application, so the [`SQLite R*Tree Module`](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) with the corresponding [`TADSQLiteRTree`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=uADPhysSQLite_TADSQLiteRTree.html) class have no meaning for me. All I need is to load `Data` field blob stream of a record found by a given `X, Y, Z` values as fast as possible.

The application will, except this database, have also a memory cache implemented by a hash table like this `TTileCache` type:

```
type
  TTileIdent = record
    X: Integer;
    Y: Integer;
    Z: Integer;
  end;    
  TTileData = TMemoryStream;    
  TTileCache = TDictionary<TTileIdent, TTileData>;
```

The workflow when asking for a certain tile while having `X, Y, Z` values calculated will be simple. I will ask for a tile the memory cache (partially filled from the above table at app. startup), and if the tile won't be found there, ask the database (and even if there won't the tile be found, download it from tile server).

### Question:

Which AnyDAC (FireDAC) component(s) would you use for frequent querying of 3 integer column values in a SQLite table (with, let's say 100k records) with an optional loading of the found blob stream ?

Would you use:

- query type component (I'd say executing of the same prepared query might be efficient, isn't it ?)
- memory table (I'm afraid of it's size, since there might be several GB stored in the tiles table, or is it somehow streamed for instance ?)
- something different ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely use `TADQuery`.  Unless you set the query to `Unidirectional`, it will buffer all the records returned from the database in memory (default 50).  Since you are dealing with blobs, your query should be written to retrieve the minimum number of records you need.

Use a parameterized query, like the following the query

```
SELECT * FROM ATable
WHERE X = :X AND Y = :Y AND Z = :Z
```

Once you have initially opened the query, you can change the parameters, then use the `Refresh` method to retrieve the next record.

A memory table could not be used to retrieve data from the database, it would have to be populated via a query.  It could be used to replace your `TTileCache` records, but I would not recommend it because it would have more overhead than your memory cache implementation.

Comment: I was hoping someone answers like that. Thanks for explaining memory tables (I've had not much time to study their principles). You're right; now when I get how do they work, it would really be just an overhead against my own in-memory cache. I will use `TADQuery` following the way of prepared queries, just changing parameters with subsequent `Refresh` calls as you've suggested. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**TFDQuery**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDQuery) with a query like follows. Assuming you're about to display fetched tiles on a map, you may consider fetching all tiles for the missing (non cached) tile area at once, not fetching tiles always one by one for your tile grid:

```sql
SELECT
   X,
   Y,
   Data
FROM
   Tiles
WHERE
   (X BETWEEN :HorzMin AND :HorzMax) AND 
   (Y BETWEEN :VertMin AND :VertMax) AND 
   (Z = :Zoom)
```

For the above query I would consider excluding [**fiBlobs**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.Items) from the [**FetchOptions**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.FetchOptions) for saving some I/O time for cases when the user moves the map view whilst you're reading tiles from the resultset and the requested area is out of of the visible view (you stop reading and never read the rest of them).